# Python struct.calcsize doesn't work for QWord

Tags: python, struct

I cannot find out why this doesn't work. I want to read one integer (double word) and 4 quadwords using struct modul. This represens 4 + 4 * 8 = 36 bytes, but python gives me this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.calcsize("I4Q")
40
```

Does anyone know why? Thanks a lot...

Comment: This is probably due to struct using 'native size' for its calculation. If you force it to use the 'standard' sizes by prepending '=' to your formatting string (i.e. `=I4Q`), you get the correct size.

Comment: [The wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding) on data structure alignment/padding is a good primer on what's happening here.  (namely, padding has to be added to align your struct members with native word boundaries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation: Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

> By default, C types are represented in the machine’s native format and
>   byte order, and **properly aligned by skipping pad bytes if necessary
>   (according to the rules used by the C compiler)**.

```
>>> struct.calcsize("I4Q")
40
>>> struct.calcsize("@I4Q")
40
```

If you specify `>`, `=`, `<`, `!`, native alignment is not used:

```
>>> struct.calcsize(">I4Q")
36
>>> struct.calcsize("=I4Q")
36
>>> struct.calcsize("<I4Q")
36
>>> struct.calcsize("!I4Q")
36
```